# Regex: Matching route parameters between slashes only but optional end slash

Tags: regex, preg-match-all

So I have this regex here:

`\/?({[a-zA-Z_0-9]*})\/?`

And I want it to match these:

```
# Valid
/test3/{id}/{test}/{id}

# Valid
/admin/{slug}

# Not Valid
/test3{id}{test}

# Not Valid
/test/{id}/yyy/{dd}/dwdw/{wd}{d}

# Valid
/user/post/{id}

# Valid
/{tt}/{t}

# Valid
/test/{id}/yyy/{dd}////dwdw/{wd}/{d}
```

But I want it to not match parameters that have no slash between them like `{id}{test}` should not match.

How can I do this?

I have setup a regex here: https://regex101.com/r/awUDhM/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for repeated patterns of `/foo`, `/{bar}`, or just an empty `/`. Code snippet:

```js
var input = [
  '/test3/{id}/{test}/{id}',
  '/admin/{slug}',
  '/test3{id}{test}',
  '/test/{id}/yyy/{dd}/dwdw/{wd}{d}',
  '/user/post/{id}',
  '/{tt}/{t}',
  '/test/{id}/yyy/{dd}////dwdw/{wd}/{d}'
];
input.forEach(function(str) {
  var result = /^(\/([a-zA-Z0-9]*|\{[a-z]+\}))+$/.test(str);
  console.log(str + ' ==> ' + result);
});
```

Output:

```
/test3/{id}/{test}/{id} ==> true
/admin/{slug} ==> true
/test3{id}{test} ==> false
/test/{id}/yyy/{dd}/dwdw/{wd}{d} ==> false
/user/post/{id} ==> true
/{tt}/{t} ==> true
/test/{id}/yyy/{dd}////dwdw/{wd}/{d} ==> true
```

Explanation of `/^(\/([a-zA-Z0-9]*|\{[a-z]+\}))+$/` regex:

- `^` -- anchor at start of string
- `(...)+` -- one or more occurances of what's inside
- `\/(...|...)` -- expect a slash, followed by a logical OR group
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` -- first OR item: only alphanumeric chars, including none
- `\{[a-z]+\}` -- second OR item: one or more lowercase chars enclosed in `{...}`
- `$` -- anchor at end of string

Comment: This is very useful, thank you for the explanation but what if I only want to match the parameters between a `{ }`?

Comment: Never mind, I was not adding the m option on the end.

Answer (score 1):

Just check if you haven't `}{` in the string:

```
^(?:(?!}{).)+$
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/pO6QBe/1)

**php code:**

```php
$strs = [
  '/test3/{id}/{test}/{id}',
  '/admin/{slug}',
  '/test3{id}{test}',
  '/test/{id}/yyy/{dd}/dwdw/{wd}{d}',
  '/user/post/{id}',
  '/{tt}/{t}',
  '/test/{id}/yyy/{dd}////dwdw/{wd}/{d}',
];
foreach($strs as $str) {
    if (preg_match('/^(?:(?!}{).)+$/', $str)) {
        echo "valid: $str\n";
    } else {
        echo "Not valid: $str\n";
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
valid: /test3/{id}/{test}/{id}
valid: /admin/{slug}
Not valid: /test3{id}{test}
Not valid: /test/{id}/yyy/{dd}/dwdw/{wd}{d}
valid: /user/post/{id}
valid: /{tt}/{t}
valid: /test/{id}/yyy/{dd}////dwdw/{wd}/{d}
```